# Running a PYTHON UTF-8 script in ANSIBLE AWX

Tags: python, ansible

I have python 3.5 installed.

There is a playbook

```
- name: test
  hosts: msk-dpro-psg351
  tasks:
    - name: test
      command: /home/support/env/bin/python3 /home/support/test.py"
```

There is a Python-script

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print('Текст на русском')
```

The code is successfully processed via `crontab` and manually run via `python3 test.py` (in env), but it doesn't work via AWX with an error:

```
print('\\\\u0437\\\\u0430\\\\u043f\\\\u0438\\\\u0441\\\\u0430\\\\u043b \\\\u043b\\\\u043e\\\\u0433')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The problem is on the AWX side, how do I make it run the script normally?

Comment: You probably need to set the locale to one that supports UTF-8. The print probably fails because the locale is `C`, which does not allow UTF-8. So for example, find a way to set the locale to `en_US.UTF-8` or another UTF-8 locale more suitable for you.

Comment: Does AWX (or more specifically, Ansible) on thatt server use Python 3 or Python 2? Python 3 strings *are* Unicode. The escape sequences seem to be correct, which suggests the script was loaded correctly but the *Python runtime* tried to handle the string as `ascii`.

Comment: You can check the locale with `import locale` `print(locale.getlocale())`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos

It uses Python 3.5 from the virtual environment. AWX only needs to run the linux command on a schedule, that's all. Cron-copes. AWX-returns an error.

Comment: Did you check what `print(locale.getlocale())` reports?

Comment: @MaxNoe 

I get `('ru_RU', 'UTF-8')` when running through the `python3` command

Comment: ok, that's strange, it should work then...

Comment: Can you try exporting `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` ?

Comment: @MaxNoe I used this - the error didn't change.

Comment: @Avraam the defaults for Python 3 changed from one 3.x version to the next, transitioning from mixed ASCII to exclusively Unicode defaults. Python 3.5 is 6 years old. Have you tried running the same script locally, under 3.5 and the latest version, 3.9? Can you try running the script on the Ansible machine directly?